# What is the optimal strategy? Random percent return

Tags: probability

Is it possible to win at a game of chance with a return = Somewhere around 1.07? What if the return ranges from 50% to 164%?
If you start with $10,000 and you can ante any number, with what strategy can you reliably (with 99% confidence) increase your bank as time goes to infinity?

Here’s my attempt:
First, I *think* that that if I ante all of my money every time, I will eventually lose everything, because the expected value of the infinite product of $x$~$U(0.5,1.64)$ will be less than one. I *think* this is true because if half the money is lost, then 64% of that gained, then half lost, 64% gained, on to perpetuity, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(0.5 \times 1.64)^n= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(0.82)^n=0$$

**However, I know I’m talking about a uniform distribution, not a coin flip**; I just don’t know how to continue with the analysis.

I think that if I ante something much less, like 10% each time, then given enough time, the game will be profitable.

Here are the monte carlo simulations I ran in excel: (30 simulations each)

For if I ante all my money (100%) every time:
[image: Graph of 30 simulations of the game, ante-ing 100% each time and taking 50 steps]
Half (15) of the simulations actually have *less* money than the starting \$10,000; all but 1 have less than (\$10,000*(1.07^50))=$294,570.

For if I ante just 10% of my money every time:

[image: Graph of 30 simulations of the game, ante-ing just 10% of bank each time and taking 500 steps]

If for each step, I only ante 10% of the bank, and I take 10x as many steps, all the final values are greater than \$10,000, and less than half but still a pretty good number are greater than (\$10,000*(1.07^50))=$294,570.

I feel like I vaguely understand why this happens, but I would like to know more about it, and if this effect has a name. I feel like a natural question is, “at what % ante does the expectation become that half of all simulations would have a final value that is greater than the initial value?”

Also, “Can varying the % ante at each step increase the expected final value?”

Also, “If given a finite number of times which the game can be played, what is the optimal % ante to put up each time to have the highest possible expected value while keeping the probability of ending with less than the starting amount to 1% chance?”

Comment: Can you clarify how the game works?

Comment: @masiewpao Essentially, each time you play the game, you input an ante, e.g. \$10. A number is picked at random somewhere between 0.5 and 1.64 (uniform distribution). That number is multiplied by your ante and you are given the result. E.g. 0.86 is picked \$10 * 0.86=you now have $8.60.

Comment: Ah OK! Also, just a small point; when you ask for the optimal strategy you should be careful to think about what exactly you are trying to optimise. In this case, no matter what ante you put up, there is always a non-zero risk of ruin (i.e. you go bankrupt). So 'optimal' depends on your risk tolerance, exactly like the 1% that you mentioned in your final paragraph. (all that to say, you need to be clear what you mean when you say 'reliably increase your bank', because this depends what you mean by reliably!)

Comment: I've found something that supplies an answer, but it more made for discrete scenarios, not continuous like I have here: the [kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion)

Comment: If I try to apply the kelly criterion to my scenario by representing the uniform variable with two discrete outcomes -- gain 32% with 56% probability and lose 25% with 44% probability -- then I get the kelly criterion of betting 7/8.